# Do the right-handed people tend to use the right side teeth of their jaw to chew food more often than the left-handed people?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy

And vice versa, do the left-handed people tend to use the left side teeth of their jaw to chew food more often than the right-handed people?
Or the frequency of food chewing distribute fairly to both sides of the jaw?

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57361/do-animals-exhibit-handedness-paw-ness-preference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Individuals have not only hand dominance but also a dominant foot, eye and ear. There has also been a belief that this sidedness applies to chewing as well. However, the short answer is that no one is sure, but that it *may* be related to handedness. I only looked at studies done after 2000.

One large study<sup>[1]</sup> found a questionable to weak correlation, not consistently maintained through different dentition (baby teeth, mixed, and permanent). A slightly smaller study showed a correlation; in 78% chewing side preference correlated with other tested lateralities (footedness, handedness, eyedness and earedness).<sup>[2]</sup> Another similar sized study found none.<sup>[3]</sup>

A small 2012 study found that there was a preference for right sidedness when chewing hard food (73.68%) and for soft food (57.89%) but failed to correlate this with hand/other-sidedness.<sup>[4]</sup> Another small study tested for sidedness, finding that 55% of subjects did not have any side preference, 30% preferred to chew on right and 15% preferred the left side, and this was reproducible in 90% of subjects *only with almonds* (a medium hardness food) as opposed to jerky or asparagus. Unfortunately they did not measure sidedness. Their findings were that chewing-side preference is not a fixed characteristic, and texture *seemed* to affect sidedness.<sup>[5]</sup> A review article determined that a person's dental condition to a large extent dictates how they chew.<sup>[6]</sup>

The studies were mostly designed very differently, making good comparisons difficult. I think it's safe to say it's possible but not known with certainty.

<sub>[1] [Absence or weak correlation between chewing side preference and lateralities in primary, mixed and permanent dentition](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22469391)</sub>
<sub>[2] [Chewing side preference as a type of hemispheric laterality](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15140165/)</sub>
<sub>[3] [Relationship between chewing side preference and handedness and lateral asymmetry of peripheral factors](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18947820)</sub>
<sub>[4] [Chewing side preference in first and all mastication cycles for hard and soft morsels](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3443888/)</sub>
<sub>[5] [Chewing-side determination of three food textures](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16409510)</sub>
<sub>[6] [Adaptation of mastication in response to the characteristics of the individual or the food](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17402223)</sub>